# Exclude category in widget through child theme

Tags: categories, widgets

I desperately try to exclude categories through following snippet in my functions.php of my child theme:

```
<?php
//https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#how-to-create-a-child-theme
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parenthandle = 'twentyseventeen-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $theme        = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( $parenthandle,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),  // If the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here.
        $theme->parent()->get( 'Version' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( $parenthandle ),
        $theme->get( 'Version' ) // This only works if you have Version defined in the style header.
    );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpdocs_exclude_categories' );

function wpdocs_exclude_categories( $query ) {
    echo "foo";
    $query->set( 'cat', '-10' );
}
```

The $query->set command seems to be processed but it does not have any effect on my category widget. :-(

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thx, Rob

Answer (score 0):

Try using WordPress' built-in filter for widget display called `widget_categories_args`. You can add a filter function to your child theme's `functions.php` that modifies the arguments passed to the `wp_list_categories()` function, which is what the **Categories widget** uses (if that's what the widget you're trying to modify) to pull its list of categories. Here's an example:

```
function filter_widget_categories_args($args) {
    $args['exclude'] = array(10); // ID of the category to exclude
    return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'filter_widget_categories_args');
```

The function `filter_widget_categories_args` will modify the original `$args` array by adding an exclude key.